# Create CheckBox in Python Flask - Jinja Template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have the below List in Python.

list_val = ['APPROVED','UN-APPROVED','DEACTIVATE']

and need to pass this list values into a Check box with Jinja Template.

**Can someone help on this with HTML code embedded with Jinja template ?**

**Expected Output:-**

[image]

**HTML Need to converted with JINJA Template.**

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="val1" name="val1" value="app">
<label for="val1"> APPROVED</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="val2" name="val2" value="unapp">
<label for="val2"> UN-APPROVED</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="val3" name="val3" value="deac">
<label for="val3"> DEACTIVATE</label>
```

Comment: in what prior do u want the checkboxes to be checked? on what conditions? do u do it manually?

Comment: I want the checkboxes to be checked and un-checked manually by user ... Could you help me with the that as well . Currently I couldn't check/un-check the checkboxes..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code

This code will have input tags with values like `approved`, `un-approved`, `deacitvate` instead of `app`, `unapp`, `deac`. Is that  okay for you?

And also its better to put the input tag inside the label tag, because when you click the word beside the checkbox, it'll toggle the checkbox (and thats why labels are mostly used for)

As W3schools says:

> Proper use of labels with the elements above will benefit:
>
> - Screen reader users (will read out loud the label, when the user is focused on the element)
> - Users who have difficulty clicking on very small regions (such as checkboxes) - because when a user clicks the text within the `<label>` element, it toggles the input (this increases the hit area).
> - **Tip:** The for attribute of `<label>` must be equal to the id attribute of the related element to bind them together. A label can also be bound to an element by placing the element inside the `<label>` element.

```py
{% for i in range(list_val_len) %}
    <label for="val{{ i+1 }}" name="val{{ i+1 }}">
        <input type="checkbox" id="val{{ i+1 }}" name="val{{ i+1 }}" value="{{ list_val[i].lower() }}">
        {{ list_val[i] }}
    </label><br>
{% endfor %}
```

And also pass the `list_val` list and its length in seperate keyword arguments on the render_template function like

```py
list_val = ['APPROVED','UN-APPROVED','DEACTIVATE']

@app.route('whatever_route_in_here')
def whatever_name_your_function_has():
    ...
    ...
    render_template('html_file_name.html', list_val=list_val, list_val_len=len(list_val))
```

Tell me if its not working...

Comment: yes it's working now Thanks a lot.... BUT , I couldn't check the checkbox values !!! Can help ??

Comment: @lazarcognos i don't get it. do u want to get the value of the checkbox? and also want to use python right?

Comment: I couldn't check/un-check the checkboxes.. Could you help me with the that as well

Comment: @lazarcognos but i can check/un-check the checkboxes actually, do u mean like toggle them using code?

Comment: Yes exactly. Currently, i couldn't able to check/un-check them. Sample working code here will be much helpful

Comment: Hi.. Any luck??

Comment: @lazarcognos i actually don't have any errors, i can click the checkboxes with no problem, i think something's wrong from your side i guess